# Como acessar um componente dentro de outro?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou usando o `single file components`, porém não consigo acessar um componente via outro componente, segue o que tentei...

```
<template>
  <div id="containerPrincipal" @click.stop="teste">
 ...
<template>

<script>
 /*Outro componente*/
 import flex_div from './elementos/Div.vue'

 export default {
  name: 'containerPrincipal',
  methods : {
   teste () {
      componente = new flex_div().$mount();
      console.log(componente);
   }
  },
  components: {
   flex_div
  }
 }
</script>
```

Erro

> _Div2.default is not a constructor

Como posso resolver isso?

**Edit**

**Div.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="flexdiv" @click.stop="opcoes">

    ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'flexdiv',
data () {

    return {
      modal : false,
      eventMod : false,
      elMod : false,
    }

},
methods : {

opcoes (event) {

  if(this.modal === true) {this.modal = false;}
  else {this.elMod = event.target; this.eventMod = event; this.modal = true;}

}

<style scoped>

#flexdiv {
  background: #424242;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Queres adicionar várias vezes esse componente ou só uma vez? podes explicar o que estás a fazer na aplicação que precisa desse componente?

Comment: @Sergio, tudo em minha aplicação é gerado dinamicamente, esse componente, será adicionado várias vezes e cada vez que for adicionado terá de ser tratado individualmente, por isso fiz dessa forma. não haverá nada pré-definido.

Comment: E ele deve ser adicionado ao DOM certo? queres inserir vários no mesmo sitio (junto ins dos outros) ou em sitios diferentes no DOM?

Comment: @Sergio Vou tentar explicar, tenho um componente inicial, quando eu clicar nesse componente, irá abrir um menu com várias opções dentre elas estilizar o componente, adicionar elementos etc... caso eu adicione um elemento no componente, exemplo uma 'div', essa div terá as mesmas opções do componente inicial ou seja quando eu clicar nessa div, ela poderá ser estilizada e poderá receber outros elementos e assim por diante, segue um exemplo disso que falei https://jsfiddle.net/044euft5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver tive de instanciar o Vue novamente e referenciar o componente...

```
<template>
  <div id="containerPrincipal" @click.stop="teste">
 ...
<template>

<script>
 /*Other component*/
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import flex_div from './elementos/Div.vue'

 let flexdiv = Vue.component('divFlex', flex_div);

 export default {
  name: 'containerPrincipal',
  methods : {
   teste () {
      let componente = new flexdiv().$mount();
      console.log(componente);
   }
  },
  components: {
   flexdiv 
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

a minha solução foi essa

```
<script>
import TableUsers from './views/TableUsers'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('TableUsers', TableUsers)

export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  data () {
    return {
      components: {
        'TableUsers': TableUsers
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```